# How is a SUBSCRIBE request can terminate a SIP dialog?

Tags: sip

How is a "**SUBSCRIBE**" request can terminate a **SIP** dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find all your answers in [rfc6665](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6665). You may take a look more precisely at Section ***4.2.1.4.  Refreshing of Subscriptions*** and Section ***4.4.1.  Dialog Creation and Termination***

Quoting some text of the rfc:

Here is the way to request the end of the dialog from subscriber side:

```
Clients can cause a subscription to be terminated immediately by
sending a SUBSCRIBE request with an "Expires" header field set to
'0'.
```

And the final NOTIFY that really terminates the dialog:

```
A subscription is destroyed after a notifier sends a NOTIFY request
with a "Subscription-State" of "terminated", or in certain error
situations described elsewhere in this document.
```